# chef client installation failure on Sles11

Tags: chef-infra, suse

I am trying to bootstrap (install chef client) the SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3 x86_64 (64-bit)server and getting below error while doing chef bootstrapping

opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.12' not found (required by /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.3)

glibc is already present 
No update candidate for 'glibc-2.11.3-17.95.2.x86_64'. The highest available version is already installed.

Help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We use the EL6 packages for SLES 11 and it sounds like SLES 11 has broken binary compatibility with the libc used by EL6. Unfortunately as SLES is a secondary platform (you can see the full package support list at https://docs.chef.io/platforms.html) it's not likely we'll have the spoons to fix this immediately. I would recommend filing a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/new). In the mean time you can try to use a gem install method but as this will be a one-off custom deal you will be unlikely to get much community support if you run in to problems. Make sure you've upgraded to the latest SLES 11 release, that might get you glibc 2.12?